# JavaFX UI hangs

Tags: javafx

I am writing a JavaFX program under ecilpse, It works well on my local machine i.e., I can execute the runable jar after I export. However, when I put the executable jar to another machine, the UI was not responding. Here are the codes I launch the javaFX program.

```
 @Override
       public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
           @Override
           public void handle(WindowEvent e) {
              Platform.exit();
              System.exit(0);
           }
        });
           this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
           this.primaryStage.setTitle("Server Simulator");
           context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:PrTrSim.xml");
           this.displayQueue = (LinkedBlockingQueue<Message>) context.getBean("displayQueue");
           this.userInputQueue = (LinkedBlockingQueue<Message>) context.getBean("userInputQueue");
           this.outgoingQueue = (LinkedBlockingQueue<Message>) context.getBean("outgoingQueue");
           this.incomingQueue = (LinkedBlockingQueue<Message>) context.getBean("incomingQueue");
           addQueue.add(this.displayQueue);
           addQueue.add(this.outgoingQueue);
           addQueue.add(this.incomingQueue);
           initRootLayout();
           showSimOverview();
       }

   public static void main(String[] args) {  
        launch(args);
    }
```

The PrTrSim.xml is for initialization of two components(messageProcessor and SocketIO reader) which are running behind.The 4 blocking queues are for message receiving and handling.

Comment: Well, as the name suspects: You are blocking the UI Thread so it "hangs". You need to do long running tasks in background so you do not block the UI Thread. There are many Tutorials around and many answers here on SO discussing the topic.

Comment: I get it solved by putting start MessageProcessor and SocketConnector using Platform.Runlater(), it seems work now. You mean I SHOULD put the code for launching UI on task ??

Answer (score 1):

To avoid blocking of the main thread you should use the JavaFX concept of tasks or services as explained in details here: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm